# Hot to make diff check a symlink link itself?

Tags: symlink, diff

In Linux one can use the command `diff` to check for differences of files. I use it to check for differences across two modules, both copied to `/tmp`.

However, both modules have symlinks, which might not be pointing to the correct file, as the modules have been copied to the `/tmp` directory. But this does not matter. What I want to check is if the symlinks are the same.

For example, in one module the symlink reads

```
/home/test/file1
```

and in the other the symlink reads:

```
/etc/rc.d/whatever
```

`diff` now throws an error because - in general - it cannot find the file. But I want to let `diff` say: "Hey, those symlinks are not the same" regardless if the links point to valid files or not.

Question: How is it possible for `diff` to do that, i.e. not trying to follow links, but to diff the links itself?

Answer (score 9):

Try GNU `diff` version 3.3 or later with the `--no-dereference` option (and presumably the --recursive option):

```
diff --recursive --no-dereference tree1root tree2root
```

The `--no-dereference` will prevent `diff` from following any symlinks. It will still compare the targets and let you know if they differ.

Comment: Could you flesh this out a little? Perhaps give an example of how it could be used? This has the makings of a perfectly good answer but we like our answers to be a bit more explicit and verbose here.

Answer (score 4):

Since version 3.3, GNU diff supports not dereferencing symlinks, but then compares the paths they point to.

Install GNU diffutils >= 3.3 and use the '--no-dereference' option; there is no short option for that.

Diagnostic will be silent if the paths are equal, or:

```
Symbolic links /tmp/noderef/a/symlink and /tmp/noderef/b/symlink differ
```

if the paths differ.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU tools:

```
diff <(cd dir1 && find . -type l -printf '%p -> %l\n'|sort) \
     <(cd dir2 && find . -type l -printf '%p -> %l\n'|sort)
```

Strictly speaking, that can't differentiate between a symlink called `a` that points to `b -> c` and one called `a -> b` that points to `c`, not to mention the problems with filenames containing newline characters, but that  makes for a more legible output than the more robust:

```
diff <(cd dir1 && find . -type l -printf '%p // %l\0'|tr '\n\0' '\0\n'|sort) \
     <(cd dir2 && find . -type l -printf '%p // %l\0'|tr '\n\0' '\0\n'|sort)
```

There, we use `//` as the separator (that cannot occur otherwise in the output of `find` for `%p`) and convert the newline characters to  NUL characters (which cannot occur in the expansion of `%p` nor `%l`).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to check that the symlinks point to the same theoretical destination, or that if one is not a symlink, the other file links to the same file. This should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$(readlink -m -- "$1")" == "$(readlink -m -- "$2")" ]]; then
    echo "files match"
else
    echo "files don't match"
    exit 1
fi
```

```
$ > foo 
$ ln -s foo bar
$ ln -s foo baz
$ ./script bar baz
files match
$ ./script bar foo
files match
$ ln -sf qux bar
$ ./script bar foo
files don't match
```

Comment: @StephaneChazelas That's my error, I meant to use `-m`, not `-f`. Thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking, that wouldn't work if the only difference is the number of trailing newline characters in the targets of the symlinks.

Comment: I would not use `-m` either.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas For what reason? Without it, relative symlinks that really point to the same file will fail this comparison.

Comment: If `/home/test/file1` is a symlink to `/etc/rc.d/whatever`, or they're both a symlink to `/`, it would report they're the same. I think the OP wants to see the difference in the "path" stored in the symlink, not whether they resolve to the same file (for which you have `[[ a -ef b ]]`).

Comment: You're right, it's unclear from the question whether the OP wants full resolution or only resolution of the first depth. Thanks for the tip about `-ef`, I wasn't aware of it, but it doesn't do what I think the OP wants, which is just path resolution (without any hardlink detection).